# 16.04 - system hangs at boot time at "Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"

Tags: system-installation, 16.04, systemd

I have an Acer Aspire One netbook with an Intel Atom CPU and 1GB of RAM. I've been using Ubuntu and a few other distros on it with no problem for two years now.

I have used both Ubuntu/Lubuntu/Xubuntu 14.04, 14.10, 15.04 and 15.10 flawlessly, with casual distro changes (Arch Linux, openSUSE, Linux Mint, elementaryOS, Debian). No problems at all. But today I decided to move back to Xubuntu, so I grabbed the "mini" installation ISO from ubuntu.com, wiped out the Debian Jessie partition and installed the system there. After the installation was completed, I installed the "xubuntu-core" metapackage and rebooted.

But the system got to a "Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes." message and sits there, with a blinking cursor. I could access other TTYs by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Fx and even startxfce4 (as root), but that issue was really annoying me. So I downloaded a Lubuntu 16.04 ISO from lubuntu.net and went to install it. As I didn't have a DVD or USB drive available, I put it in a backup partition and booted the Lubuntu installation media with GRUB2, using

```
set root=(hd0,msdos4)
loopback loop /lubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso
linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/lubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.iso config noprompt noeject
initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
boot
```

But it also got stuck in the exact same message. The difference is that now I can't change TTY, but I think it's because it's a live media. Some people suggested it may be a graphics driver problem, but I'm not sure. I also saw a similar problem with some Mageia folks.

Can someone help me?

Comment: See also [Boot stopped at Started Update UTMP About System RunLevel Changes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391612/boot-stopped-at-started-update-utmp-about-system-runlevel-changes-headless-s) on Unix & Linux SE.

Answer (score 3):

I landed here by googling 'lubuntu 16.04 started update utmp about system runlevel changes'. I saw this same message and I thought the system hanged. But actually I could ctrl-alt-f1 and switch to console. Eventually this thread solved my problem:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321317&p=13478810#post13478810 In short, I did `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel` and rebooted, then everything went ok.

My background situation is different from yours, though. My setup is quite simple -- it doesn't involve loopmount. However, it was not a straight install either. I installed lubuntu in a lenovo x220i notebook, booted into a different partition, tar czf the lubuntu 16.04 partition, transferred the .tgz to an old computer (which I can't find make and model for now), tar xzf the image into an empty partition, and set up the extlinux boot loader.

Answer (score 1):

If you loopmount, you would see some udates, like FRONT_BACKEND=original and also --- instead of just -- and so on.

Anyway, I think the new installers have some logic issues with detecting the media, when you loopmount from a hard drive. And it doesn't seem to cp it over to /cdrom but maybe it should have been /media.

Either way, I recall having this issue and I don't remember if I resolved it as I don't use ubuntu. Either way, you should get into the seed installer if , as I say, you take a little look at updated boot commands.

Comment: That's strange because I always do it the exact same way with older releases and it always works (even though I have to forcefully unmount `isodevice` with `sudo umount -l /isodevice`). Anyway, I ended up installing Lubuntu 14.04, which works flawlessly, but I'd really like to use the new LTS release.