# Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded and now I can't boot to desktop, NVIDIA drivers are related

Tags: 16.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

I've got kind of a huge problem in my Ubuntu 16.04.

Yesterday I turned the computer on, and was working in my stuff when a message where "some important updates will be installed" appeared. Innocently, I selected the "yes" option.

Then the problems started to appear.
Mendeley desktop failed to start, so I ran it from terminal an got this kind of error:

```
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat
```

I didn't pay too much attention to it, thinking it was a problem of the program itself.

But today I couldn't boot the computer. It normally starts with the BIOS screen (The Ultimate Force is its name), then a gray screen 3 seconds, then a quick list of processes, most of them developed as a green [OK] (thus some got a red [FAILED]) and then boots.

This time after that screen, it appeared another short list where the first 2 lines were the following:

```
Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
[ OK ] Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
```

Then screen turns black. But I could get to tty1 using Ctrl+Shift+F1.

As of it, I looked for information in forums like this one, and tried a solution of the following link:
[Ubuntu 16.04 nvidia drivers don't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761136/ubuntu-16-04-nvidia-drivers-dont-work)
from which I followed the next codelines:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
sudo apt-get install intel-gpu-tools
```

Reboot

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-yyy
```

Where yyy were any of 396, 390, 384, or 375. Nothing happened, still same issue.

But when yyy was any of 304 (nvidia-current version seems to have stopped in 304) or 340, error changed and the process list I mentioned before, starts saying something like this:

```
[ FAILED ] Failed to Start Snappy Daemon
A start job is running for ...
```

Where ... didn't show well what it it was exactly doing, but it were multiple things including, of course, Snappy Daemon (which truly I don't have idea what it is). That kept looping with some weird number code and didn't let me get to any tty. So I was forced to restart manually the computer and follow these instructions:
[How do I boot into a root shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell)
where from I could uninstall those old NVIDIA drivers and reinstall the newer ones (installed 384, the one I had before the issues) to, at least, access the tty easily.

Viewing no advance, I tried the next instruction:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia*
```

Which told me that couldn't proceed because "I held broken packages", but something called my attention: ALL the nvidia drivers were informed to have conflict with something called `xorg-driver-binary`, while the newer had conflict with `nvidia-smi` and `nvidia-persistenced`, from which my logic is that somewhere there was the specific problem that I had at the beginning.

Then maybe I did something really dumb in my desperation.
Seeing another 2 conflicts, that I show here:

```
nvidia-libopencl1-384 : Conflicts : libopencl
nvidia-opencl-icd-384 : Conflicts : nvidia-opencl-icd
```

I thought it was a good idea to install manually those components:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-libopencl1-384
sudo apt-get install nvidia-opencl-icd-384
```

Called my attention that they were not installed before. So I did it, rebooted, and the error changed.
This time after the quick process list screen, it appeared another short list where the last first and last lines are the following:

```
Starting Thermal Service Daemon...
...
[ OK ] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
```

So i followed [16.04 - system hangs at boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769026/16-04-system-hangs-at-boot-time), installing xserver-xorg-video-intel, with no results.

Important data of output of `inxi -b` are more or less the following:

- Kernel: 4.13.0-39-generic x86_64
- Machine model SABERTOOTH 990 FX R2.0
- Graphic Card: NVIDIA GM204 (GeForce GTX 970)
- Graphic Display Server: X.org 1.18.4
- Graphic Driver: FAILED: nouveau

So then i did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install *nouveau*
```

And error persisted, with the difference that `inxi -b` or `inxi -Gx` didn't tell anymore that nouveau driver failed.

So after all that, I think somewhere there is the main problem (Nouveau as driver instead of the nvidia installed ones), but I don't know how to change that.

Also, I can't turn off Secure Boot mode as other posts suggest because ASUS UEFI BIOS does not have that option (just has "Windows", or "Other Systems").
Neither I can post the real output of some commands since I don't know how to copy them from the damaged computer to this one in which i'm typing this.

I'm giving up for now, but I'm worried because I have important files in this computer and I wouldn't want to do a 16.04 fresh install, since I read that wasn't a sure way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do You have `cuda toolkit` package installed? Purge it completely as well as any nvidia drivers and install from https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa version `390.59`, it's long supported driver with cuda precompiled in it so no extra cuda toolkit installation is needed....and You showed some conflicts with files which are included in the likes of `nVidia 390.59` driver...if this won't work do reverse action and switch to `nVidia 396.24` + additionally instal `cuda toolkit` after that, maybe there will be no conflicts. If You have Intel + nVidia and still nVidia installed so You have e.g. `nvidia prime` package try to get into root and type in terminal `mount -o rw,remount /` (and optionally `mount --all`) to mount partition (or all partitions mentioned in /etc/fstab) in read/write mode and then `prime-select intel` and reboot. If You can get into ubuntu without root mode then just type `sudo prime-select intel` and reboot. After that You have safe use of ubuntu under Intel and can fix nVidia from that point.
Prime select has:
`prime-select intel`
`prime-select nvidia`
`prime-select query` use.